# Experimenting with Aurora, not seeing that it is fast with queries

Tags: amazon-aurora

I am trying Amazon Aurora for my MySQL database. My DB is about 600 GB when I run mysqldump. I have an instance running locally, one in my VPS, and one with Aurora (which I uploaded and within the last 24 hours).

When I run "select sql_no_cache * from employees;" on each of these three environments, I am seeing that Aurora takes much longer to return just over 1 million records. I am trying to compare apples to apples as best as I can. I have run this query over MySQL Workbench and a terminal. The results are about 3.5s locally and VPS to 214s on Aurora.

Before I give up on Aurora, any idea why I am seeing perf results that I would never have expected with a technology that boasts 5x the performance over standard MySQL? Is querying my Aurora DB like I would my MySQL DBs (with either Workbench or terminal) an unrealistic test for performance? Do I need to do some further configurations or tuning?

I believe Aurora is fast, so I must be doing something wrong. If it is this slow to query from my end, then I would expect if my app were to query it, it would be similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, measuring the response time for a single `select sql_no_cache * from employees;` query returning 1 million records from a Workbench/Terminal client on your local workstation connected to to an RDS Aurora instance is an unrealistic test for performance. Not only is it not an apples-to-apples comparison, but your app also doesn't (or shouldn't) behave similarly when it queries the database in production.

First, to compare apples to apples:

- Run your test on servers with identical computing power (CPU speed/count, RAM, disk I/O). If your local workstation, VPS, and RDS instance are different, this will affect your comparison. Compare an RDS instance running Aurora to an RDS instance running MySQL of the same exact instance type (e.g., `r3.8xlarge`).
- Establish your test client/server connection across identical network boundaries. Sending a million rows of data across your laptop's Internet connection can take a long time compared to sending them across a local socket from an instance running locally. Make sure that your test servers are located in the same general network (e.g., that they're both in the same region/availability zone in AWS), to make sure that the network connection has consistent properties.

- Use the same query and the same source data (it sounds like you are already doing this).

Second, to run a test similar to what you would expect if your app were to query your database:

- Measure concurrent-query throughput (requests per second), not individual-query performance (seconds per request). For relational databases, the number of concurrent transactions your database can handle (which limits how many users your app can handle) can be as important (or more) than the amount of time an individual query takes to complete in isolation. [`sysbench`](https://github.com/akopytov/sysbench) is a standard DB-benchmarking tool that launches a bunch of concurrent queries and measures requests/sec.
- Run a large number of small queries, not a single, large query. Though your app may be different, web apps tend to pluck small amounts of individualized data for a large number of concurrent users (think of a web page displaying detailed info about a single object, rather than a million objects on a single page). The OLTP (online transaction-processing) benchmark in `sysbench` provides a [set of queries](https://github.com/akopytov/sysbench/blob/b16976cf2e23f4ec8ce7478fdb289f289e86c76d/src/lua/oltp_common.lua#L246-L274) similar to typical web-application workloads. Long-running, full-table-scan type queries are better optimized on data-warehouse products like Amazon Redshift.
- Establish your client/server connection from another machine in the same network as the DB. Your web server should be deployed as physically close to the DB as possible so network bandwidth is high and latency is low. Otherwise, the network connection can be a bigger bottleneck than anything else.
- Use a large, multi-CPU instance for testing. Many of Aurora's optimizations focus on scaling read+write throughput linearly across multiple CPU cores. With a tiny, single-CPU instance, you probably won't see much throughput improvement over MySQL. The `r3.8xlarge` instance type has 32 CPUs, and will perform much better with Aurora's optimizations.

To reproduce the exact performance benchmark Amazon uses, you can follow the gritty setup details in the [Amazon Aurora Performance Benchmarking Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20190331064417/https://d0.awsstatic.com/product-marketing/Aurora/RDS_Aurora_Performance_Assessment_Benchmarking_v1-2.pdf).

For specific numbers behind the 5x performance claim, see Verbitski et al. (2017), ["Amazon Aurora: Design Considerations for High
Throughput Cloud-Native Relational Databases"](https://web.archive.org/web/20220112202454/https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/files/p1041-verbitski.pdf):

> Aurora’s performance doubles for each higher instance size and for the r3.8xlarge achieves 121,000 writes/sec and 600,000 reads/sec which is **5x** that of MySQL 5.7 which tops out at 20,000 [writes]/sec and 125,000 [reads]/sec.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response. You make valid points. My apples to apples comparison will not be as simple as I described, so I will need to do more work for a fair comparison to determine if Aurora will meet my needs. Thank you again for response.